# What does it mean convert to concrete Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to understand the template haskell from page https://ocharles.org.uk/guest-posts/2014-12-22-template-haskell.html.

We are going to take this example:

```
runQ [| 1 + 2 |]
InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1))) (VarE GHC.Num.+) (Just (LitE (IntegerL 2)))
```

As you can see, the expression is evaluated into AST.
And with

```
$( return (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1))) (VarE (mkName "+")) (Just (LitE (IntegerL 2)))))
3
```

it evaluates the AST, right?

The question is, do every expressions in Haskell convert to AST before compiling?

The author mentioned in the article:

```
Ta da, you converted concrete Haskell to AST and then evaluated it.
```

in connection with code:

```
$( return (InfixE (Just (LitE (IntegerL 1))) (VarE (mkName "+")) (Just (LitE (IntegerL 2)))))
3
```

What does the author mean with the concrete Haskell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The question is, do every expressions in Haskell convert to AST before compiling?

Conversion to some form of AST or another is usually part of compilation, yes.

> What does the author mean with the concrete Haskell?

The concrete part refers to `1 + 2`, not the AST.